# Implementing Heat Map on Google Maps using a combination of langitutde, altitude and Energy consumption

Tags: java, android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

I'm using android studio to create a heat map on google maps. I have a database consisting of the following information:

```
longitude   latitude    Electricity Energy Consumption 
1 -77.08527 38.7347905  4.742112594
2 -19.03592 34.8081915  4.742112594
3 -74.04591 12.8815925  5.278542493
4 -32.05547 25.9549935 12.270006486
5 -49.06596 76.0283945  4.742112594
6 -63.08492 20.1017955  4.742112594
```

Is there any way to take these coordinates and magnitude and plot a density map using Google Maps?

I've done a bit of research, and the google api does allow the creation of the heatmap  but it only allows a dataset containing coordiantes. How would I reflect the energy consumption in certain areas?

This is the link to the site that tells you how to create a heatmap: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/utility/heatmap

I just need a push in the right direction to be able to implement this.

There is the following method that I thought I could use but I didnt quite understand it and was hoping maybe someone could explain how to use it, and if its possible to use this to implement my particular scenario:

This is the code from the site to implement the heatmap which only take into account the coordinates:

```
   List<LatLng> list = null;

    // Get the data: latitude/longitude positions of police stations.
    try {
        list = readItems(R.raw.police_stations);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Problem reading list of locations.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    // Create a heat map tile provider, passing it the latlngs of the police stations.
    mProvider = new HeatmapTileProvider.Builder()
        .data(list)
        .build();
    // Add a tile overlay to the map, using the heat map tile provider.
    mOverlay = mMap.addTileOverlay(new TileOverlayOptions().tileProvider(mProvider));
}

private ArrayList<LatLng> readItems(int resource) throws JSONException {
    ArrayList<LatLng> list = new ArrayList<LatLng>();
    InputStream inputStream = getResources().openRawResource(resource);
    String json = new Scanner(inputStream).useDelimiter("\\A").next();
    JSONArray array = new JSONArray(json);
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
        JSONObject object = array.getJSONObject(i);
        double lat = object.getDouble("lat");
        double lng = object.getDouble("lng");
        list.add(new LatLng(lat, lng));
    }
    return list;
}
```

This is the code from the site to change the dataset:

```
ArrayList<WeightedLatLng> data = new ArrayList<WeightedLatLng>();
  mProvider.setData(data);
  mOverlay.clearTileCache();
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of LatLng, you can use [WeightedLatLng](http://googlemaps.github.io/android-maps-utils/javadoc/com/google/maps/android/heatmaps/WeightedLatLng.html).

You code should look like:

```
List<WeightedLatLng> list = null;

// Get the data: latitude/longitude positions of police stations.
    try {
        list = readItems(R.raw.police_stations);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Problem reading list of locations.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    // Create a heat map tile provider, passing it the latlngs of the police stations.
    mProvider = new HeatmapTileProvider.Builder()
        .weightedData(list)
        .build();
    // Add a tile overlay to the map, using the heat map tile provider.
    mOverlay = mMap.addTileOverlay(new   

    TileOverlayOptions().tileProvider(mProvider));
}

private List<WeightedLatLng> readItems(int resource) throws JSONException {
    List<WeightedLatLng> list = new ArrayList<WeightedLatLng>();
    InputStream inputStream = getResources().openRawResource(resource);
    String json = new Scanner(inputStream).useDelimiter("\\A").next();
    JSONArray array = new JSONArray(json);
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
        JSONObject object = array.getJSONObject(i);
        double lat = object.getDouble("lat");
        double lng = object.getDouble("lng");
        double magnitude = object.getDouble("mag"
        list.add(new WeightedLatLng(lat, lng, magnitude));
    }
    return list;
}
```